# Save float value (UIFontSize) By NSUserDefaults

Tags: size, nsuserdefaults, uifont

How to save float value (UIFontSize)by NSUserDefaults?

```
(void)pinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{NSLog(@"*** Pinch: Scale: %f Velocity: %f", gestureRecognizer.scale, gestureRecognizer.velocity);

UIFont *font = self.bioTextView.font;
CGFloat pointSize = font.pointSize;
NSString *fontName = font.fontName;

pointSize = ((gestureRecognizer.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize;

if (pointSize < 13) pointSize = 13;
if (pointSize > 26) pointSize = 26;

self.bioTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:pointSize];
```

Comment: You've not told us what the problem is with the code?

Comment: Code work perfectly, but i want to save those value by NSUserDefaults

Comment: Oh my bad, could have at least given it a go first: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGesture:)];

// And add it to your text view.
[self.bioTextView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

UIFont *font = self.bioTextView.font;
NSString *fontName = font.fontName;

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([prefs objectForKey:@"floatKey"]==nil) {
    self.bioTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:18];
} else {
    float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];
    self.bioTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:myFloat];
}
}


- (void)pinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
NSLog(@"*** Pinch: Scale: %f Velocity: %f", gestureRecognizer.scale, gestureRecognizer.velocity);

UIFont *font = self.bioTextView.font;
CGFloat pointSize = font.pointSize;
NSString *fontName = font.fontName;

pointSize = ((gestureRecognizer.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize;

if (pointSize < 13) pointSize = 13;
if (pointSize > 26) pointSize = 26;

self.bioTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:pointSize];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setFloat:pointSize forKey:@"floatKey"];
[prefs synchronize];
}
```